# pass more than one variable in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```
app.factory('dataPassingService', function() {
var savedData = {};
function set(data) {
    savedData = data;
}
function get() {
    return savedData;
}

return {
    set: set,
    get: get
}
});
```

controller1

```
$scope.text = '9';
     dataPassingService.set($scope.text);
```

controller2

```
 $scope.mes = dataPassingService.get();
 alert("the scope is "+scope.mes);
```

I pass the $scope.text from controller1 to controller 2 using app.factory and it work perfect. i would like to pass more scopes together from controller1 to controller2 for example i would like to pass $scope.text='9' and scope.text1='10' and then with the take it to the controller2 with datapassingService.get().Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You could pass in a key to uniquely identify each different piece of data, for example:

```
app.factory('dataPassingService', function() {
    var savedData = {};

    function set(key, data) {
        savedData[key] = data;
    }

    function get(key) {
        return savedData[key];
    }

    return {
        set: set,
        get: get
    }
});
```

Usage:

Controller 1

```
$scope.text = '9';
dataPassingService.set("myKey", $scope.text);
dataPassingService.set("message", "foo");
```

Controller 2

```
$scope.mes = dataPassingService.get("myKey");
$scope.message = dataPassingService.get("message");
alert("the scope is " + $scope.mes); // the scope is 9
```